# Is each word correctly grouped with words of a similar vowel sounds?

Tags: pronunciation

I have got the following English words. I want to arrange and put those that have similar vowel sounds together in a group. I have already arranged them but I am not sure.

Rift Sick Rich Sieve

Keep Peach leave siege

Tight wife Buy

Hat Man Band Blood

Hate Wait Weight Pays

Hot What Shop Wrong

But Ton

Dark Half Heart Fast

Comment: This varies so much from region to region that there is no single right answer

Comment: "Buy" for example might rhyme with "wife" in some accents but with "boy" in others. What is the purpose of this exercise? If it is homework or similar it would depend entirely on which country you are studying in, or which accent you are learning.

Comment: user4065, which British accent? There isn't just one.

Comment: Again, is this for a particular English class that you are taking? If so, we can't answer here. You have to use your ear and listen to the accent around you.

Comment: As others have said, it's hard to say definitively. That said, I don't think _blood_ belongs with those other words; plus, I think _dark_ and _heart_ are fine together, but _fast_ belongs with _hat_.

Comment: If you scroll down to the big chart you will see how complicated this is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects

Comment: @J.R. I personally agree with you on "fast" and "hat" belonging together, but my Kiwi boyfriend has a completely different vowel sound for each. He might as well be saying "fost" and "het".

Comment: nxx and J.R., good points. There are also pronunciations that mean *fast* does **not** belong with *hat*.

Comment: and in my dialect a) *hot* and *shop* have the same vowel, but *what* and *wrong* have two different vowels b) *half* and *fast* belong with the *hat* group, but *blood* belongs with *but* and *ton*--and *what* c) *tight* and *wife* have a diphthong but *buy* has an allophonic monophthong.

Comment: i think in all dialects "what" and "blood" should go in the same category as "but" and "ton"

Comment: hunter, not in all. In England and the rest of the UK, the word *what* has a different vowel sound from *blood*, *but* and *ton*.

Comment: I disagree with @hunter about "what" but agree about "blood". In British English "What" is correct to rhyme with "hot". "Wrong" is similar to the hot/what group you have it in, but not identical - at least not in my accent.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a mid-american, I would group them:

short i: rift sick rich sieve

long e: keep peach leave siege

long i ("uhh-ee"): tight wife

long i ("ahh-ee"): buy

short middle a: hat half fast

short back a:man band

long a ("ehh-ee"): hate wait weight pays

short o ("ahh"): hot shop

short u: what but ton blood

"ar": dark heart

"aw": wrong

I'm not sure how to describe the difference in pronunciation between "hat" and "man" but there is a definite, if subtle, change.  For me it's a pulling-back of the corners of the mouth which adds a touch of "eeee" to the "aaa".

Comment: I didn't realize that anyone pronounced "buy" with a different vowel from "tight"! That's fascinating

Answer (score 2):

This is based on my pronunciation. I'm from London; based on the descriptions on Wikipedia, I'd describe my accent as closer to [London Accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_accent#London_accent) than [Estuary English.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estuary_English).

Borrowing the terminology from Hellion's answer:

short i: rift sick rich sieve

long e: keep peach leave siege

long i: tight wife buy

short a: Hat Man Band

long a: Hate Wait Weight Pays

short o: Hot What Shop Wrong

short u: But Ton **Blood**

ah: Dark Half Heart Fast

Note that "fast" is pronounced with an "ah" in some part of the UK, and with a short a in others. Also, short o in my accent (and other British accents) is shorter than in American accents; so "hot" and "heart" have very different vowel sounds, whereas they may be more similar in some American accents.

Regarding the idea of there being a "British accent": there's no such thing; [there are many British accents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_accents_of_English).